# DOCKER: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: port, docker, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

I have tried so-many ways to solve this issue but i don't no where i struck again i got same error like this...

```
! Unable to load application: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**This is my DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2
# Install node.js

RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/nvm
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.15.1

RUN curl 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash \
&& . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
&& nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
&& nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
&& nvm use default

 ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
 ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
 ENV GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle"
 ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH

 RUN node -v
 RUN npm -v

 RUN echo -e "s/[#]\?listen_addresses = .*/listen_addresses = '*'/g" -i '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf'
 RUN echo -e "host    all    all    0.0.0.0/0    md5" >> sudo /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf

 # Install global Ruby dependencies
 RUN gem install bundler -v '1.17.3'

 ADD . .
  # Install Ruby gems
  RUN bundle install
  EXPOSE 3001
  # Stop on SIGINT (Ctr-C)
  STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
```

**This is my docker-compose.yml**

```
 services:
   server:
    build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: universum-businessprofile:local
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis
  - openssl
ports:
  - "3001"
  volumes:
  # This volume is just to simplify development process and not to rebuild image after each change
  - ./:/app
  # The following volume is required for communication between server and jobs
  - ./public:/app/public
env_file:
  - ./.env
environment:
  - ACCESS_YEAR
  - BP_URL
  - REDIS_PORT
  - REDIS_HOST
  - EMPLOYEES_MFOS
  - DIR_RANKING_YEAR
  - META_RANKING_YEAR
  - RDS_DB_NAME
  - RDS_USERNAME
  - RDS_PASSWORD
  - RDS_HOSTNAME
  - RDS_PORT
  - SENTRY_API
  - SIDEKIQ_USERNAME
  - SIDEKIQ_PASSWORD
  - SUPER_MAIL_ID
  - TABULATOR_API_URL
  - TABULATOR_USERNAME
  - TABULATOR_PASSWORD
  - UA_API_URL
  - USE_SENRTY
  - USE_SSL
restart: always
command: ./bin/run_local_server.sh
 jobs:
image: universum-businessprofile:local
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis
ports:
  - "3001"
volumes:
  # This volume is just to simplify development process and not to rebuild image after each change
  - ./:/app
  # The following volume is required for communication between server and jobs
  - ./public:/app/public
env_file:
  - ./.env
environment:
  - ACCESS_YEAR
  - BP_URL
  - REDIS_PORT
  - REDIS_HOST
  - EMPLOYEES_MFOS
  - DIR_RANKING_YEAR
  - META_RANKING_YEAR
  - RDS_DB_NAME
  - RDS_USERNAME
  - RDS_PASSWORD
  - RDS_HOSTNAME
  - RDS_PORT
  - SENTRY_API
  - SUPER_MAIL_ID
  - TABULATOR_API_URL
  - TABULATOR_USERNAME
  - TABULATOR_PASSWORD
  - UA_API_URL
  - USE_SENRTY
restart: always
command: ./bin/run_local_jobs.sh
 redis:
  image: redis:3.2
  ports:
  - "6379"
  restart: always
  db:
    # In production we use 9.4.20 (and we are going to upgrade it to 10.4)
image: postgres:10.7
volumes:
  - ./ci/db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ports:
  - "5432"
restart: always
 openssl:
  image: frapsoft/openssl
volumes:
  - ./tmp:/export
command: req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -sha1 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -subj "/C=US/ST=Colorado/L=Colorado Springs/O=SW/CN=localhost.ssl" -keyout /export/localhost.key -out /export/localhost.crt
restart: "no"
```

**This my evn File**

```
    BP_URL=http://localhost:3001/
    DB_PORT=5432
    DIR_RANKING_YEAR=2016
    JOBS_PORT=3002
    REDIS_PORT=6379
    REDIS_HOST=redis
    RDS_DB_NAME=businessprofile_dev_1
    RDS_USERNAME=postgres
    RDS_PASSWORD=postgres
    RDS_HOSTNAME=db
    RDS_PORT=5432
    SERVER_PORT=3001
    SIDEKIQ_USERNAME=sidekiqadmin
    SIDEKIQ_PASSWORD=UniversumBP
    UA_API_URL="http://localhost:3000/api/"
```

Comment: I don't believe there is enough to reproduce this error since you are running `ADD` on files we do not have access to (see [mcve]). The indentation on the compose file is incorrect and yml files are white space sensitive. Is evn a typo or some other file format? Please describe what debugging steps you have already taken, noting that there are [lots of similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+localhost&mixed=0)

Comment: It looks like you are connecting to localhost instead of the host db, which is where the postgres container will be.  It also looks like you're trying to change some postgres configuration files in the ruby/node container, which won't help.

Comment: @Jeremy explain how can i change it